# Корректный запуск программы

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить следующую ситуацию: когда я запускаю программу (форму1), на которой расположено около 50 различных контролов (текстбоксы, чекбоксы, лейблы, группбоксы), то после появления контура формы, контролы на форме как бы появляясь прорисовываются в течение нескольких секунд. Как это исправить?

Comment: Простой вариант все контролы поместить на скрытую панель. Показать надпись Подождите... После того, как основная форма закончит загрузку, надпись подождите скрыть, а панель со всеми контролами показать.

Comment: Возможно для этого подойдет событие Shown у формы подробнее https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx

Comment: Спасибо! с Shown запуск выглядит лучше.